Please unlock, undelete, & reopen closed ID questions in line with our community consensus
As you may be aware, our community has recently reaffirmed its support for identification questions. Relevant previously featured June 2024 meta discussion post: What does the community want to do with identification questions? This decision has led to several important updates:

The identification close reason has been removed.
Our site tour and help center have been updated to remove references to the ID ban.
Stack Exchange staff have unblacklisted the ID tags.

However, there's one more step we need to take: addressing the previously closed identification questions.
When the ID ban was implemented back in 2018, a moderator mentioned that the mod team asked Stack Exchange staff to automatically close all existing identification questions and apply a historical lock. This lock prevents non-moderator users from voting on (including voting to reopen), flagging, or editing these questions.


Closing all existing questions (starting 15 days from now):

We will ask SE for help in automatically closing all existing identification questions and, for the time being, applying a historical lock to them (which makes them unvotable and uneditable by non-moderator users, as well as removing them from normal question lists).

- Napoleon Wilson. "We are discontinuing support for identification questions"
Relevant meta post: Identification Question Cleanup: Closing existing questions.
The moderator also mentioned that they would be "cleaning up the existing [ID] questions." As a result, 3,726 ID questions were mass-deleted during the February 2018 ID question cleanup (for example), along with 684 questions deleted by the moderators after the February 2018 cleanup. Relevant meta post: Identification Question Cleanup: Deleting old questions.

Thus we will be deleting all existing identification questions unless they meet all of the following criteria:

They have a score of +5 or more.
They have at least one answer with a score of +3 or more.


- Napoleon Wilson. "Identification Question Cleanup: Deleting old questions"
Given our community's clear consensus to allow ID questions, I believe it's time to reverse these actions. I'm requesting that we:

Unlock these "historical significance" locked ID questions.
Undelete any ID questions that were previously closed and deleted for being off-topic under the old guidelines.
Reopen the closed ID questions.

Since the initial mass locking, closing, and deleting involved Stack Exchange staff, I'm hoping our moderators will add the status-review tag to this post. This will escalate the issue to SE staff, in line with the process outlined in the Meta Stack Exchange post: "What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?"
Keeping these questions locked, closed, and deleted despite our clear community consensus and policy to allow them, will confuse users and send the wrong messages about our site policy.

Note: I initially flagged this post requesting a status-review tag but was declined with the reason: "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention."
I believed this was precisely the type of post requiring moderator intervention, as only moderators can add the status-review tag. Despite the flag decline, a moderator has since added the status-review tag. Could the moderator team clarify the reasoning behind these actions?

Where can we find the current (consensus on) guidelines for the ID questions? I cannot seem to find the post.

@Joachim The current community consensus is at What does the community want to do with identification questions? (It's been featured for 30 days.)

@Joachim The ID guidelines are at Tips for asking Movie/TV Identification questions

For transparency, the tag has been unblocked, and I am currently sorting out how to restore all the questions.

@SpencerG I appreciate the update! Would it be feasible to tackle this in steps? We could start by unlocking the questions, then reopening them, and finish by undeleting those that were deleted. This approach might make the process more manageable.

@galacticninja Is there a list of the locked questions? I don't think I saw one anywhere.

@SpencerG I’m not aware of a list, but I believe all questions with the ID tags prior to the recent unblacklisting were locked and closed, and most were deleted, according to this 2018 meta post made by a moderator at the time. There’s also an answer in that post where a CM discussed the implementation. That CM or the moderators involved at the time would likely be the best sources for more details.

@SpencerG Alternatively, you could identify affected questions by looking for those closed for the reason that they're ID questions. These should be unlocked and reopened. Similarly, ID questions deleted by moderators or SE staff (as opposed to automatically by the Community bot / Roomba) should be undeleted.

I'm planning to have this wrapped up before the end of November. In the meantime: should the unlocking, undeleting, and reopening be applied to all questions that fall under that criteria, or are there additional criteria (date, score, etc.) that should be taken into consideration here?

@JNat Based on our community consensus, identification questions are now considered on-topic, regardless of when they were posted or their scores. The community and moderators have already reopened some of these questions, irrespective of age and score. I believe that any question previously closed for being an identification question should be unlocked, reopened, and undeleted.

@galacticninja that should not be the case as many one liner question also got closed which only had negative votes and community only closed them.

@JNat I would strongly advise to apply this only to the questions that were mass-closed/deleted/locked during the ID ban in '15 for now. There have been myriads of terrible questions that have been closed and deleted over the entire history of this site for various valid reasons. Resurrecting them all injudiciously really sounds like a terrible idea.

If you end up bringing back the rape fantasy questions in this process, you will have really dropped the ball on this. ;-)

@JNat I’ve seen several good-quality ID questions get deleted by a moderator even years after the 2018 ID ban, and it doesn’t seem fair to leave them that way. If a question has to be closed again for other reasons, the community can handle that. But it doesn’t seem right to let these valid questions remain deleted just because a single mod chose to delete them.

@JNat I suggest starting with unlocking the questions closed for being ID questions. That way, the community can vote on which ones to reopen or undelete. The original mass-locking wasn’t consistent with SE's historical lock policy, as I mentioned in my answer, so unlocking is a more fitting first step than undeleting.

@NapoleonWilson I’ve noticed quite a few perfectly fine ID questions that were closed and deleted just this year, by you during your time as a mod. I managed to initiate undelete and reopen votes on a few of them, and some even received useful answers later on. If users could search through deleted ID questions, I believe we’d find plenty that the community would want to keep. It doesn’t seem fair to keep everything deleted just because of some lower-quality posts; the community can always step in to close anything that doesn’t meet our standards.

@galacticninja That wasn't what I was saying. If we got questions that would have been perfectly fine without the topic-ban, then yes, they could get reopened. But just undeleting every damn ID question wholesale after the community put in a ton of effort and work to moderate them even before they were banned, seems like a seriously flawed idea. That's why I said, start with the mass-closed/deleted ones for now, then see about the ones asked after the ban. But you won't get around some actual judgement if you don't want to flood the site with shit people spent genuine effort to clean up.

The idea of "just resurrect everyone and let the community sort everything out yet again at square zero" (which of course noone will actually do anyway) basically trashes years of community work put into maintaining the site.

But while undeleting and reopening old questions is an option, you also have to live with the fact, that you can't get back every great question asked during the years long ID-ban. That's just how it is. In the same way we haven't gotten rid of all the ID questions when they were banned. Site scope is ultimately a living and developing thing and if someone's question got closed yesterday when it would be on-topic tomorrow, then that's just how the history of the site develops. If they're really interested in it, they might have to ask it again.

@galacticninja "just because a single mod chose to delete them". You should be thinking twice about what you are saying right now. A mod's vote is final one but it doesn't mean that a single mod chose that. A moderator did as per the site's scope at that time.

@Valorum, the terrible idea is bringing back every ID, even those that were just spam or one-liners where the user never showed up again with dozens of downvotes. Your intentions are a bit concerning.

@NapoleonWilson AJ, and AnkitSharma I suggest posting your thoughts as answers here so the community can weigh in. I think restoring ID questions selectively isn’t the best approach. I’ve seen several ID questions that were deleted by moderators after the 2018 ID purge, and many of these are actually good, on-topic questions that our community currently would probably want to see reopened and undeleted.

@AJ Sure, a moderator acted within the site’s scope at the time, but our community has since reopened and undeleted several questions Napoleon previously closed and deleted, aligning with our current site scope. It’s also worth noting that some recent ID deletions happened even after it was apparent that the community leaned toward keeping ID questions open.

I'm stepping in here to remind everyone to keep the conversation constructive as we reach a consensus on how to proceed.

@JNat To help the community assess the scope of the ID question restoration effort, would it be possible for you to share data regarding the number of mod-deleted ID questions since the February 2018 ID question mass deletion? (Link leads to relevant meta post.)

I'll try looking into that this week, @galacticninja

Though not overwhelming, it seems like the consensus is that this request should apply, for now, to questions that were cleaned up by a CM (read, me) in February 2018. I'll aim to work to satisfy that request this week.

@JNat Please note that Valorum's answer has more upvotes than Napoleon's answer. Given that it requires 125 rep to downvote and only 15 rep to upvote, considering Valorum's answer as better reflecting the community consensus is more fair to members with less than 125 rep. Otherwise, you are giving double weight to the votes of users with 125 rep or higher.

@galacticninja It seems fair (more or less) to give more weight to the people who've actually participated in the site. 125 rep is like a single answer's worth, hardly a huge feat. If someone doesn't have 125 rep (or even for most of the people who do), do they actually know enough about how the site works to have a meaningful opinion on a big site-moderation issue like which selection of questions should be reopened? They won't be able to help with any of the community moderation of closing/reopening, that's for sure.

@Randal'Thor I think it’s more fair to give every user’s vote the same weight, especially when it comes to policy discussions. One user, one vote seems like the most equitable approach. Given how much harder it is for new users to earn reputation now compared to years ago, favoring higher-rep users would be unfair and disproportionately benefit those with older accounts. Also, having over 125 rep doesn’t mean someone is actively participating on the site currently. …

@Randal'Thor …And since you need 3K rep to close or reopen questions, it’s not like they’re necessarily contributing to those moderation efforts either.

@galacticninja It feels more like you're trying to find excuses to favour the outcome that you personally prefer. Why should we allow votes from people with more than 15 rep but less than 125 rep, precisely?

@Randal'Thor Good question, but that’s a question for SE, not me.  My take is that SE set it up this way to promote upvoting (which give rep) over downvoting (no rep gain). While this works well on the main sites, it doesn’t work as well for policy discussions on meta sites. For instance, on Arqade Meta, we run a "Screenshot of the Week" competition where we only count upvotes, not the total score with downvotes, to be fair to users with less than 125 rep.

@Randal'Thor This approach is pretty standard for polls and community consensus on SE meta sites, so I’m not sure why there’s pushback to giving users with less than 125 rep the same voting weight.

How can an answer whose score nears 0 due to its highly polarized reception be considered representative of consensus, @galacticninja? How is that not the opposite of consensus? Furthermore, your hypothesis ("you are giving double weight to the votes of users with 125 rep or higher") hinges on a voting distribution pattern across the two posts that is not present.

@JNat The way I see it, more users seem to favor Valorum's answer over Napoleon's. It would be strange if Napoleon's answer still wins in that case. In elections, you vote for what you support, not against what you don’t. So, treating the votes as upvotes only, like in an election, feels fair and straightforward. I hope that helps explain my point!

To add to the above, Napoleon's suggestion was to delay the restoration of the closed/deleted questions made after the 2018 ID ban for another time. There were only 684 of them compared to the 3726 questions deleted during the ban. Since only mods can undelete these mod-deleted questions, and users can't even search for deleted questions except their own, the restoration will be completely up to the mods' discretion, increasing their workload, and I don't recall any member of the mod team agreeing to dealing with the huge task of reviewing all those questions. …

… With only one active mod handling ID restoration flags, the mod team will probably have to ask the CMs again to restore these questions.

@galacticninja "This approach is pretty standard for polls and community consensus on SE meta sites" - citation needed. AFAIK, there's no single standard for how to define what constitutes a "consensus". I think you should take the win (some thousands of deleted ID questions are about to be undeleted) instead of arguing the toss with a CM (if they feel they can't do anything here without needing lengthy comment discussions about the details, they might not be inclined to help with this kind of thing next time).

The good news is that things are progressing in multiple directions. We now have a figure for how many questions were deleted as ID during the ban period (684), and Napoleon's answer doesn't rule out undeleting them later. His strongest point was "not to do anything to the questions closed/deleted before the ID ban (or god beware, all the questions tagged identify-this-...)", which makes sense as those questions were moderated without a rule of ID being totally off-topic, and I think that's the major difference between his and Valorum's proposals, rather than the 684 questions.

Here's how I see it (and maybe the italics in my original comment about consensus was missed), @galacticninja: we can undo the automated actions taken in 2018 now. Y'all can debate what you wanna do about the 684 other questions and request that later, once y'all have agreed that's what you wanna do — as I mentioned, there's an almost even split between folks who think those should be undeleted now, and those who don't; the other approach doesn't have as much contention, clearly, so it seems like a safe action to take now, without further debate. CMs are happy to help later, once again ;)

@JNat Sounds good to me. We shouldn't delay restoring those 3,726 questions just because of the 684 mod-deleted ones. Plus, having those ID questions restored will help drive engagement on the site.

Just to clarify, my earlier comments were meant to point out that calling Napoleon's answer the consensus isn't as simple, given it didn't win the popular vote. Valorum's answer actually received more upvotes, indicating a different community preference. I'm not suggesting we hold off on restoring the 3,726 ID questions mass-deleted in February 2018 because of the 684 mod-deleted ones from after that date.

I understood the intention of your comments, @galacticninja, and I think you misinterpreted the intention behind my initial comment. I said there was consensus that the 3,726 should be undeleted, etc., now. To make the implicit part in that statement explicit: there is no consensus on how to proceed for the other 684.

@JNat Ah, I see what you're saying now. The 3726 ID questions from 2018 are a clear-cut case—they should all be restored. But the 684 mod-deleted questions after that are still a point of contention, so we can discuss those separately later. It would be helpful to get a list of those 684 questions so the community can review and discuss which ones to undelete. (I’ll follow up with a meta post once the 2018 ID questions are restored, and hopefully, the CMs can provide the list.)

Should we move all the ID questions that were asked on other exchanges to here since they should have been here in the first place?

@galacticninja "Just to clarify, my earlier comments were meant to point out that calling Napoleon's answer the consensus isn't as simple" - Of course it isn't. But neither is it simple to call the one with the most upvotes a "consensus" when it is actually more contested simply because you don't like counting downvotes when they disagree with you (when the whole reason we're here is counting trickling downvotes across 6 years). Maybe stop trying to argue toe and nails that the "true consensus" is exactly what you have in mind if only we'd all count "properly". ;-)

This request has been processed. All of the following actions will appear as having been performed by me.

Undeleting: Of the 3,726 questions I deleted in February 2018, 3,711 were undeleted. The remaining 15 were not undeleted because they'd been originally migrated from Science Fiction & Fantasy, and those migrations had been rejected and thus deleted over there too, so you'd be left with a stub pointing nowhere.
Unlocking: All the posts locked by Shog9 in 2018 were unlocked — that's a total of 4,686 posts. All of the posts on the group above this one are a part of this group.
Reopening: All the posts closed by me in 2018 were reopened — that's a total of 4,686 posts (this list is the same as the above). All of the posts on the groups above this one are a part of this group. (huh, yeah, and all of these got bumped to the front page)

If you notice something off, or that I may have missed something, please let me know.

Thanks! By the way, I noticed that a question that had been migrated to SF&F SE has also been reopened: Looking for a movie title. Help?. I'm not sure if this and others like it should also be reopened.

@galacticninja - I've seen a few of those. I've flagged them for a mod to close if they're open on SFF

Keeping previously closed, locked, and deleted identification questions in their current state presents several issues:

We may find ourselves in the awkward position of needing to close new identification questions as duplicates of closed and locked ones. This goes against best practices, as we typically avoid closing questions as duplicates of closed questions, let alone locked ones. For example, we recently had to navigate this issue with the question "Horror show where the protagonist has really nice-tasting blood". While we resolved that particular case by reopening and unlocking the target question, similar situations are bound to crop up if we don't take action on all affected questions.

The current message on locked questions states, "This question and its answers are locked because the question is off-topic but has historical significance." This is no longer true for identification questions, as they are now on-topic. Also, it's a stretch to claim that all 976 (not deleted) and 3,726+ (deleted) closed identification questions truly have historical significance.

The current blanket locking doesn't align with Stack Exchange's policy on permanent "historical significance" locks. According to this policy, such locks should be used sparingly and primarily for questions of exceptional historical or cultural value, and  should not be used for any other purpose:

Permanent locks should almost never be used, with the exception of those imposed by the system itself. There are some exceptions:

An extremely popular question which is now considered inappropriate for the site may be locked for "Historical significance": this alters the appearance of the question, automatically locks all answers as well, and disables flagging completely. This lock should be reserved for cases where a cherished cultural artifact would otherwise be deleted; do not use it for any other purpose.




By unlocking, undeleting, and reopening these questions, we can create a more consistent experience for users and ensure our past content aligns with our current policy. This action would foster a more welcoming environment for those interested in identification questions and prevent potential confusion or frustration for both new and existing users.

Some moderators, in the comments, have suggested taking a selective approach to restoring identification questions rather than the comprehensive restoration outlined in the feature request. However, I believe this approach overlooks several important factors.
Most, if not all, identification questions deleted by a moderator after the 2018 ID questions purge (including several in 2024) were actually good questions with enough detail that would likely receive community support today. In fact, we've already seen evidence of this—our community has successfully reopened and undeleted several previously closed identification questions, doing so based on the questions' merit rather than their age or score. Some of the undeleted questions have even received correct answers; opportunities that would have been permanently lost had the questions remained deleted.
We already have a system in place to handle low-quality content. The Community user's automated cleanup scripts, AKA Roomba, automatically remove questions with zero or negative scores that meet certain criteria. If any problematic posts do slip through, our community can evaluate and close them through the normal question review process.
Given these safeguards, there's little risk in taking a comprehensive approach to restoring these questions. The potential benefit of recovering valuable content far outweighs any temporary moderation overhead we might encounter.

Also, unlocking these question will allow us to point users at them as potential duplicates. Why are we trying to re-invent the wheel when we've already identified a thousand movies?

Unlocking and undeleting also allow new answers, comments, edits, and votes, which are each important for different reasons.

We don't have tools to undelete and re-open thousands of questions.  It took weeks to get the tags re-allowed by StackExchange staff, and undeleting the questions is being worked on.  Its not a high priority for the company.

And seriously rather than sniping about deceitful moderators or obstruction please open a meta question asking for all the moderators to step down and fresh elections to be called by SE.  I wouldn't be against that.  Discussions over deceit in the past is a bit pointless.  I have my opinions and while I dislike being called deceitful, its kind of irrelevant.  However if people think we are being obstructive now, which I feel is unfair, then I would happily demonstrate that I am not in it for 'power' and step down.

[comments above not in response to galacticninja, but a comment about why this had not been completed yet and whether moderators were obstructing this]

@iandotkelly - Historically, calling for a moderator (or set of moderators) to stand down has proven ineffective everywhere I've seen people doing it.

That being said, Movies:SE is well (well) overdue for new elections. Two of the mods were elected a decade ago and the most recent was elected half a decade ago. All three standing down and asking to be re-elected would be a powerful way of demonstrating that the moderation team has the support of the current community.

@Valorum But Richard, on the one hand you say calling for new moderators is ineffective (and by extension the implication I suppose is, that you won't do that then). Yet on the other hand we repeatedly see comments by select few users that the moderators should be replaced or we need new elections, be that direct and honest (like here) or sarcastic and underhanded (as happens, too). That is neither fish nor meat, I'm afraid. I can't continuously complain in comments all the time, yet not want to actually take it into a serious meta discussion with the excuse that "it won't do anything anyway".

That is merely a recipe for having a constant status quo of complainery and animosity towards the moderation team. It is very much the same vicious circle the ID situation has been trapped in by a select few users over the last years. And it only got broken because uninvolved users took it to meta for being fed up with the conflict it shed across the rest of the site. If that status-quo of anti-moderation sentiment is not intended (there are of course also reasons why someone might want to retain this), at some point the complainery and dissatisfaction has to move out of the comment section.

@NapoleonWilson - You're assuming that posting a meta is the same as posting a comment. If I post a comment directly addressed to IanDotKelly saying "I think the mod team is well overdue for a change" that's merely an opinion and I'm not expecting others to support or oppose it. If I post it as a meta, I have to expect others will respond and may choose to respond (for example, a moderator may take it personally and decide to victimise me) in ways that I can't really control or foresee.

@Valorum And that's a bingo. It is a test for the community support of an opinion and a commitment to engaging in that opinion in a serious way. I understand that not everyone might want this opinion to be put to the test in such a way or commit as seriously to such an opinion. But then one also has to live with the fact that nothing ever comes from voicing that opinion in comments. (And if moderators would groundlessly vistimise everyone who annoys them, there would be a lot more suspensions. ;-))

@NapoleonWilson - There's also the fact that I'm basically a magnet for polarised drama. People often seem to support and oppose me, rather than necessarily reading my reasoned arguments and making their own damn mind up.

@Valorum "There's also the fact that I'm basically a magnet for polarised drama. People often seem to support and oppose me, rather than necessarily reading my reasoned arguments and making their own damn mind up." - That is likely true, yes. But that is also the consequence of a strong and outspoken personality. I could say by now it's the same with part of the moderation team, or how I instinctively downvote all MSE posts by SE employees. However, that is also a chosen fate, for the moderators as much as for you.

I'm also in favor of a new moderator election, but not because I want the current team to step down. Rather, it's because we appear to have just one active moderator doing most of the work. I only see one moderator undeleting, unlocking, and reopening flagged ID/trivia questions, addressing meta posts, and properly handling outdated comment flags. The others seem either inactive or, in some cases, actively working against community consensus by declining valid flags.

For a site our size, we really need a full team of at least three active moderators to effectively manage the flags/workload and maintain open communication with the community.
