How to undelete my two Movie ID questions that were locked for "historical significance" that may now be on-topic?
I have two questions that became off-topic (Movie ID), were then closed, then locked "for historical significance" and then after that, deleted by a different moderator.
I'm not sure why the deletion was necessary, nor how many Movie ID questions were deleted, but I'd like to know if my two questions could be undeleted, unlocked, and re-opened now that Movie ID questions are no longer off-topic.

What does the community want to do with identification questions?
Bringing back identification questions
Temporary tags for ID questions while awaiting the unblocking of ID tags

The questions are:

Old movie were a Gregory Peck-like actor jests about "the Brownies" (currently unanswered)
Which comedy film contains a highly stylized, rapidly cut sequence of drinking? (1 answer with +4) Screenshot:


Also, if there are new guidelines for ID questions, perhaps on new tags, please let me know where to find these.

https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/please-unlock-and-reopen-closed-id-questions-in-line-with-our-community-consensu

@Paulie_D I've asked for un-deletion of two specific questions here, I'm not seeing that addressed there. There is a big difference between locked and deleted.

Undeletion is only done AFAIK by the Community Team and they are reviewing the request. This may take some time.

@Paulie_D are they reviewing locked and deleted posts or just locked posts? That is not clear from that page.

Apparently, the 2018 ID question ban involved mass deletion, not just locking and closing as I'd assumed. Now that we've changed our policy to allow ID questions again, these deleted posts should be restored. I suspect many of them, like yours, are high-quality questions with enough details for proper identification.

@galacticninja Is there some knowledge of how many deletions we're talking about? Dozens? Hundreds? A few thousand?

@uhoh Not sure. Only moderators can answer that since regular users can't search for deleted questions other than their own.

There are just over 1000 deleted ID questions.  I could undelete 10 every couple of days so as to not flood the front page. (this was incorrect - see below).

@iandotkelly - You'd be done by Easter.

Hmm, I don't know what went wrong with that query earlier - when I do it now there are 16,296 results with 'identify-this-movie' alone

I don't think I'm opening 30 a week and taking over 10 years to complete it. I thought 1000 seemed light, but over 16,000 is suprising, we have less than 24,000 open questions in total.

@iandotkelly - Easter 2034, I meant.

@iandotkelly That's quite a lot to sift through. I wonder if it could be narrowed down by excluding the auto-deleted posts by the Community bot / Roomba for having no answers and low scores. It might be more manageable to focus on those specifically deleted by moderators or SE staff.

@iandotkelly According to JNat, the SE staff member involved in the 2018 ID question cleanup, there were 3,726 questions deleted in the 2018 ID cleanup, which seems more manageable compared to the 16K you mentioned. Maybe the extra 12K deletions are from the Community bot / Roomba, unless moderators have also been mass-deleting ID questions.

@galacticninja perhaps a smaller number have a positive score and/or an answer with a positive score. There may be additional "quality" filters as well, perhaps questions which were posted by users still active and likely to accept a good answer?

I have undeleted, unlocked and re-opened the posts you highlight here.
